# Own IEnumerable.First(...) implementation without implicitly captured closure (ReSharper)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, closures

I basically want to create my own implementation of LINQ .First(item =>...) and .Single(item => ...), objects only, which throws an exception with a meaningful message for the logfile:

```
var items = new List<Item>();
// fill items...
var itemIdToFind = 1234; // not supposed to be constant
var itemFound = items.First(
    i => i.ID==1234,
    () => new NotFoundException("Item " + itemIdToFind + " not found in items"));
```

Implementation is like this:

```
internal static class MyExtendedLinq
{
    public static T First<T, TEx>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<TEx> notFoundErrorFunc)
        where TEx : Exception
    {
        var firstOnly = elements.Where(predicate).Take(1).ToArray();
        // don't confuse found default value with default due to element not found - not FirstOrDefault!.
        if (firstOnly.Length == 1) 
        {
            return firstOnly[0];
        }
        throw notFoundErrorFunc(); // don't care for null func in example
    }
}
```

This keeps giving me the Implicitly Captured Closure warning from ReSharper, both for the Exception lambda and the predicate function.

Especially for the Func predicate, I see no difference to the regular LINQ First(predicate) implementation, which doesn't show this warning.

I don't want the meaningless InvalidOperationExceptions from the regular First(prediate) method, leaving people searching for days, where something expected is missing.

Comment: Honestly you *probably* just want to turn the whole warning off.  It's almost always going to be a false positive (as is the case here), and even if the code *is* extending the lifetime of an object longer than needed, it's unlikely to be by enough, and for an expensive enough object, to be a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in your case is that you have two different lambdas, each of which are closing over *different* variables.  `Enumerable.First` only has a single lambda, so it can't do that.

Now, you don't need to *care* about this warning, because neither delegate is long lived (neither will even outlive either variable), so there is no *problem* here.  Of course, Resharper can't know that, and so has chosen to warn you about it so that you can determine that there isn't actually a problem here.